# Source Control (svn) Best Practise About an Upgrade of a Framework

Tags: svn

We had an upgrade of an old web site, porting it from .NET 2 to .NET 4.

What's the best practise about an upgrade of a framework?
Should I create another project folder in the root of the repository (along with the old one), or should I create another branch inside the old/existing project folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should you support both platforms simultaneously? If not, why bother? Maybe just create a tag to bookmark a revision before upgrade just in case.

Comment: So your answer is: "tag the 2.0, continue with the trunk". The thing is: it's not clear WHEN we'll use the upgraded version, so we'll continue to have the 2.0 in production and 4.0 in develop. I know it's awful, but a developer is quite resilient to communication with the team.